# htaccess rewrite rule not loading site content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am struggling with .htaccess rewrite rules.
Let's say I have this URL.

```
localhost/site/index.php
```

and I want to rewrite it as this URL

```
localhost/site/tutorial
```

I would use this RewriteRule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^tutorial/(.*)$ /up/index.php
```

The page works, but the CSS files don't load.

Also, if I have a URL like this:

```
index.php?page=home
```

Then I would have to parse through that URL to get 'home' not using $_GET anymore correct??

Comment: For the record, grammar is not out of style.

Comment: where is your css file? why do you expect it work with such a `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use absolute URLs for your CSS file, or at least reference from domain root.

```
http://www.mysite.com/css/myCssFile.css
```

or

```
/css/myCssFile.css
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^tutorial/(.*)$ /up/index.php
```

This will rewrite anything that goes to the tutorial directory as `/up/index.php`, which means that unless you host your CSS file at that location, it won't work. If your css file is at `/tutorial/css.css`, it will redirect it to `/up/index.php`

You would have to parse through the %QUERYSTRING% in order to redirect based on `index.php?page=home`

Answer (score 0):

So the CSS files are not loading because you are changing the location of the served file.

So if you are linking to ./css/style.css => ^/tutorial/css/style.css is not the same as /up/css/style.css

And you can retain the get if you rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^tutorial/(.*)?(.*)$ /up/index.php?$2
```