# rewrite rule does not load site content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this Rewrite rule to load different page for Russia, using cloudflare IP Geolocation.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^(RU)$

RewriteCond $1 !^(__test)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ russia.html [L]



DirectoryIndex index.html
```

The problem is that russia.html loads only text content.
I have tried to use absolute URLs for CSS file as stated here [htaccess rewrite rule not loading site content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274001/htaccess-rewrite-rule-not-loading-site-content) but with no results.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these 2 conditions on top:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

That way all existing files and directories are excluded from the rule.

Comment: this disable russia.html and index.html loads everytime.

Comment: The purpose of the conditions is to exclude any existing file, like css, js, images, etc., from the rule, to allow the pages to display properly. I didn't test your rules as that wasn't part of the question, but did they work as expected before the modification, except for the problem you describe?

Comment: Could you please post any testing request to have an idea of the incoming URL structure?

Comment: Yes they work fine. Now its ok. All I did is to add this RewriteCond $1 !^(folder_files)

Comment: Fine. That's something I was going to suggest but needed a request sample.